# In Visual Studio for a C# project, where does the list of exceptions to break on get stored?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, exception

In Visual Studio, there is a list under Debug > Exceptions (Ctrl-Alt-E) that shows which exceptions the debugger should break on.  Where does this list get stored?

I ask because my list is being constantly reset (and all of my System exceptions are being disabled, so all of the important exceptions don't break at all) and I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: I think this is stored as part of suo file. Your list may be resetting due to improper shutdown of visual studio. Just a guess.

Comment: @Sandeep might be on to something: perhaps your source control (assuming you are using one) is mashing your suo file.

Comment: We don't keep the .suo file in the repository, it's local only.  Visual Studio does crash quite often, that might explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guessed it right... It is actually stored in the Solution User Option (suo) file right next to your solution. You need to save it correctly once to keep your exception list persisted.

Here is an article from John Robbins along the same lines 
http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/04/03/customizing-exception-handling-in-the-vs-debugger.aspx